# Registering other company on iOS developer program

Tags: iphone, registration

I am working as iOS freelance developer for one non-IT company and now my application is almost finished so I need to create iOS developer program account for their company.

Problem is that I am not employed in that company, I am just working app for them and they want me as their subcontractor to register their company on their name for iOS developer program.

So is it possible that I fill and create iOS company developer program for their company, so that they need only fax documentation and speak to Apple if they called them?

Can I be their admin, and how do I do that so they have access to financial i sales report?

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an Apple developer account for that company. You will have to specify a contact person and the position inside the company and some company documentation that you will have to fax later.

When they verify everything the company account will be created and you/they can check financial and sales reports by log in in the iTunes connect portal.

I recommend you use some generic company email address during the creation process like operations@company.com, so they can have track of everything going on.

Comment: just one more question...
what about paying $99 dollars? how company can pay?

Comment: In my case I asked them to use the company credit card

Comment: what if they do not have company credit card?

Comment: why not pay it yourself and invoice the company (seeing as you are a freelancer).

Comment: well someone has to pay for that and I think the only method is using credit card. If you pay and claim that money to them bear in mind than after one year they will have to renew the certificate and I am not sure how easy is to change payment details.

Comment: thank you, I just wanted to know whether someone else can pay, and now you confirm me.
When I need to provide information about credit card? On the beginning or after registration ends?
Sorry I'm bored

Comment: you can complete the registration and then pay for the 99$ when Apple accept you request(which will take 2-3 weeks) If I remember well :), please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: What company documentation do we need to fax to apple?

Answer (score 1):

You can just enroll them into this program and give them the id and password and guide them about the usage of it so that they can manage it themselves. But then that's only an option.

If you ant to know how to enroll and how to go about with this. then here's a guide.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/